# Pandas - Combining resample value cont

Tags: python, pandas

I looking to resample my data per minute and find out how many pass fail my data has per minute.

Currently this is what the data looks like:

```
timeStamp Results    
1589443200000 Pass       
1589443201000 Fail       
1589443202000 Pass       
1589443203000 Pass       
1589443204000 Pass       
1589443321000 Pass       
1589443325000 Fail
```

What im after is something like the following:

```
time       Result     Count      
8:01:00    Pass        4
8:01:00    Fail        1
8:02:00    Pass        1
8:02:00    Fail        1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert unix times to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then aggregate counts by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) with [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
df['timeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timeStamp'], unit='ms')

df1 = (df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='timeStamp', freq='Min'), 'Results'])
        .size()
        .reset_index(name='Count'))
print (df1)
            timeStamp Results  Count
0 2020-05-14 08:00:00    Fail      1
1 2020-05-14 08:00:00    Pass      4
2 2020-05-14 08:02:00    Fail      1
3 2020-05-14 08:02:00    Pass      1
```

Or if want [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) and times by [`Series.dt.time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.time.html):

```
df['timeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timeStamp'], unit='ms')

df1 = (df.groupby([df['timeStamp'].dt.floor('Min').dt.time, 'Results'])
        .size()
       .reset_index(name='Count'))
print (df1)
  timeStamp Results  Count
0  08:00:00    Fail      1
1  08:00:00    Pass      4
2  08:02:00    Fail      1
3  08:02:00    Pass      1
```